# What does the field h_flags indicate in wynsure tables

Tags: oop, ewam

I was of the impression that the field h_flags is used in Wynsure tables to indicate that a particular object is locked. Now, I see that the field h_flags is being used in some of the reporting queries and not sure of the correct purpose of it. Also couldn't find much documentation around it in the eWAM help. Can someone please help understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There area a number of technical fields eWAM's Persistancy engine that are hidden or appear differently in eWAM. Here is the list of fields as they look from outside of ewam (MSSQL or Oracle, DB2...)

related link:
https://mphasiswyde.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TT/eWAM+Databases

**NSID**           Name Space ID (representation of the class in the database) 
    **ID**         ID number of instance, like a serial #  
    **Version**        Technical Version of the Instance   
    **H_CLID**         used principaly to know the class to instanciate when loading the object as long as several classes are stored in same table. It is used also for OQL   
    **H_CLVER**        class version : to know the exact class version of the object   
    **H_THREFCount**               
    **H_REFCOUNT**         handles the  integry relashionship at the version level (nb of objects that references this version with a refto/listof integral)   
    **H_UPDATEDATE**           date when the object is stored :there is Wam API to get these values    
    **H_UPDATETIME**           time when the object is stored :there is Wam API to get these values    
    **H_ISCURVERS**        shows that the row is corresponding to the current version of an object (this column does not exist when the object is mono versioned)  
    **H_ISKILLED**         applicative deletion (eWam API : KillThing())   
    **H_FLAGS**        technical flags that handles : freezing, referential integrity and cascade deletion 
    **LASTUSER_NSID**          Key Fields  to the Last application User who Modified the object.   
    **LASTUSER_ID**        "   
    **LASTUSER_VERSION**           "    Note that -1 denotes that the RefTo points at the latest version, not to a specific version    
    **MIGRATIONDATE**          Marked by wMigrate  
    **NAME**           THE "Name" variable from aWFUserSignedItem  
    **MYOWNER_NSID**           Key Fields  to a given referenced object (refto)    
    **MYOWNER_ID**         "   
    **MYOWNER_VERSION**        "   
    **CREATIONDATE**           time stamp of the object's Create Date (the time will be null)  
    **CREATIONTIME**           time stamp of the object's Creation Time, (the date will be saved as well)

Comment: Thanks Brian, this is very helpful. Could you please provide some more detail on h_flags and its usage. I am not sure how this is used for maintaining referential integrity. Would it be defined based on the programmers' intent.

Comment: All the H_* flags are for eWAM to use (behind the scenes) with a few exceptions, like, when you are on a refto or listof role and you are setting the parameters, things like Freeze and Is Integral, will result in some of these getting flagged, it's not a 1 to 1 though, you don't code around this, except to check (or not check) the boxes.